# Possible Network Plan? routed Subnets with www and Mail trunk

Tags: routing, firewall, subnet

i mean the following is not possible..

We plan to create different Networks for Subareas with same Address-pools.
With tricky Routing to use same IP-Settings on the Devices, there were moved around on these subnetworks.

The device must have Internet (www) connection and Access to the Data server(10.0.0.2).

So is it possible ? If yes, is the the thinking below correct?

[image]

Comment: I won't say it is impossible, but I can't imagine why you would try to do this this way.   What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  I'm sure there are easier ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Ron, we had a evolved historically network. These Device on different areas now talking to each other areas, thats isn't want anymore. But also they don't want to change the IP-Settings on this devices.  The Device must have the able to use in different areas without changing the IP-Settings. So far i hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: What kind of routers/switches do you have? If Cisco, you might be able to use access lists or private VLANs to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: VLANs, recabling or re-IP-ing are necessary. You can't just move a device from within one network prefix to another segment with a different prefix. Don't do "tricky routing" or any non-standard magic. You will regret it, I promise.